# Samsung Galaxy s4 starts up, then notifications from all apps that they have stopped working

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

So i've just cleared the cache in recovery mode on my rooted Galaxy S4 (I9515) and i rebooted. And now it takes a long time to get past the splashing samsung sign, and when it does i get a bout a hundred popups saying that apps have stopped working, and after that the screen remains black, and all i can do is hold te power button to get the shutdow, restart etc. menu. How can i fix this without factory reset? Dont know if it matters but i use nova launcher as the default launcher

Comment: Your best bet is to flash a stock rom via a PC with Odin. Go to [sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I9515/) and download a stock firmware. Preferably for your region. Follow the instructions given on the download site

Comment: The launcher shouldn't be the culprit. Did you try to wipe the Dalvik cache, since you also wiped the normal cache?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I factory reset the phone and now it's working again, i don't know what happened but this fixed the problem.